# How to change the style of button when navigating to corresponding page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

In my master page there is four buttons.It have mouse hover css property. Each buttons response page is defined on the same master page.Now I want to change the button style when user is on corresponding page. How is it make possible? My master page contains below code

```
<style type="text/css">
.side_btn_css {
 width: 200px;
 height: 85px;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #fff;
 line-height:20px;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color:#b30000;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #ffffff #b30000;
 border-width: 15px;
 }
.side_btn_css:hover
{
width: 200px;
height: 85px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;
line-height:20px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color:#0a4241;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #ffffff #008080;
border-width: 15px;
}

.side_btn_css_focus
{
width: 200px;
height: 85px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;
line-height:20px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color:#3333ff;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #000000 ##3333ff;
border-width: 15px;
 }
 </style>
<div id="left_buttons" style="size: auto;">
<asp:Button ID="bt_home1"   runat="server"   CssClass="side_btn_css"  text="Home1" Font-Size="Larger" onclick="bt_home1_Click"/> <p />
<asp:Button ID="bt_home2"  runat="server"   text="Home2" CssClass="side_btn_css"  Font-Size="Larger" onclick="bt_home2_Click" />
<p />
<asp:Button ID="bt_home3"  runat="server"  CssClass="side_btn_css"  text="Home3" Font-Size="Larger"  onclick="bt_home3_Click"/>  <p />
<asp:Button ID="bt_home4"  runat="server"   CssClass="side_btn_css"  text="Home4" Font-Size="Larger" onclick="bt_home4_Click"/></div>

protected void bt_home1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Response.Redirect("home1.aspx");  
}
protected void bt_home2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Response.Redirect("home2.aspx");  
}
```

Comment: do you have different controllers for each page?

Comment: @RaphaelParreira  yes

Comment: I don't know asp.net very well. But you can set `CSS Classes` server side, selecting the button by `id`. So you manipulate exactly the button that you want! I'll do some research for you.

Comment: Maybe this helps you.... bt_home1.Attributes.Add("class", "side_btn_css_focus");

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Jquery in your page, this will make your coding easy. (you can do it by JavaScript as well but Jquery is easy way to do)

You have to add class to button depending on which page is requested. For that you have to get name of that page from requested url and form JQuery Selector as below.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var page = url.split('/'); 
    page = page[page.length-1].replace(".aspx","");
    $("#bt_"+page).addClass("side_btn_css_focus");
});
```

You can prefix some other text for Side menu and top menu.